# Which ID to use store the entity locally

Tags: sharepoint-addin, guid, custom-web-app

I am building an app where I need to store the Sharepoint Entities locally. Which of the following Ids is best suited for such scenarios?

1. GUID.
2. Unique Id.
3. Id.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your scenario:

1. Unique ID / GUID - is unique GUID that identifies an item in SharePoint content database, but using SharePoint API you cannot find item using this GUID.
2. Id - is item ID in SharePoint list/library, that is integer value and is incremental.

Usually, when you want to uniquely identify list item in SharePoint you should use this set of properties:

1. Web Url - string
2. List ID - GUID
3. Item ID - integer

Having these 3 properties, you can easily identify and get any SharePoint list item in whole SharePoint Farm, using server side API, client side API or REST Web Services.